# SKSpritenode not responding in TouchesBegan

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

In my game, when player contact with a flag (using DidBeginContact) I add an SKSpritenode "nextlevel" (which is not responding in TouchesBegan and I don't know why. The NSLog code in TouchesBegan is not working.

This my code:

```
-(void)nextlevel
{
    nextlevel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"nextlevel.png"];
    nextlevel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    nextlevel.name = @"nextlevel";
    nextlevel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0, self.size.height / 2.0);
    [self addChild:nextlevel];
}


- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }


    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask == playerCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == flagCategory) ||
       (firstBody.categoryBitMask == flagCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == playerCategory))
    {
        // PLAYER WINS
        NSLog(@"player touches flag");
        SKAction * wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.2];
        SKAction *performSelector = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(nextlevel) onTarget:self];
       [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, performSelector]]]; 
    }
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    // Nextlevel splash screen
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"nextlevel"]) {
        NSLog(@“Next Level was touched!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Set nextlevel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your `SKSpriteNode` is obstructed by another Node on top of it.
Try setting the `zPosition` above all other nodes. Try different values depending on the zPositions of the other nodes in your scene.

```
nextlevel.zPosition = 10.0f;
```